# Paypal error : "Your Paypal session has timed out" when accessing site in standalone mode in iOS

Tags: ios, paypal, iphone-standalone-web-app, ios-standalone-mode

In my app(site) I use Paypal.

But when I open in `standalone mode` and try to initiate payment process sandbox paypal page gets open in same mode.

when I click **"Pay with PayPal"** button as shown in image, it opens new safari tab (however it should stay in `standalone mode`)
And it gives **"Your Paypal session has timed out"** error.

It works successfully when I use browser.

I don't know is this the issue of cookies or something else?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]